# Execute non-anonymous function on definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myFunc = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

    myfunc();  

    jQuery('#type-selector').change(myFunc);
});
```

The purpose of this code is that I need function `myFunc` to be executed on both `document.ready` event and `onChange` event. This code works perfectly, however I wonder is there a way to avoid the call `myFunc();` and execute the function on its definition instead? In other words I need to keep the reference on function object and execute function "in one line".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
jQuery('#type-selector').change(
    (function() {
        alert('test');
        return arguments.callee;
    })()
);
```

This function returns itself when called  (`return arguments.callee`).
I call the function immediately, then pass its return value 9which is the same function) to `change` as the event handler.

This is confusing code; I don't recommend using it.

Comment: @Felix: No; `caller` is deprecated.

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe I confused it with `Function.arguments` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)) good to know because it is handy for recursive functions :)

Comment: That is what I was looking for, but not sure whether I will use this. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 4):

You could trigger the `change` event:

```
jQuery('#type-selector').change(function() {
    alert('test');
}).change();
```

or

```
jQuery('#type-selector').change(myFunc).change();
```

Comment: Surely this would not be seen as a better way to code it than the original?  The original is straightforward, easy to modify, and easy to read.  This version gives up those nice aspects to be terse.  +1 anyway.

Comment: @John: I would say *it depends*. Maybe defining the function beforehand and then calling `jQuery('#type-selector').change(myFunc).change()` is better. Assigning the handler and triggering the event seems to be quite logical.

Comment: That second version looks sort of weird because you call "change()" twice and one registers a callback and the other invokes it.  It's just weird.  :)  I give you credit for telling the OP how to do what he wanted, but I am more asking the OP to consider, now that he has what he asked for, if it's really better.

Comment: @John: You can also use `.trigger('change')` ;) I think it is a matter of how much one is used to jQuery.

Comment: Trigerring change event is not a good idea, because it will also run other handlers attached to event which is not needed. Anyway, thanks for all yur replies, I will use the obvious variant without looking for any hacks